# vs 2015 cannot go to metadata definition and it shows one or more errors occurred

Tags: visual-studio-2015

It works when I click go to definition on the code that exists but it doesn't work if I click one in the metadata such as String, List.
Pressing <kbd>ALT+F12</kbd>, a blank page appears.
Pressing <kbd>F12</kbd> shows:

> one or more errors occurred

[image]

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is a bug being tracked at [Microsoft's bug tracker](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1577587) as well as on the [Roslyn issue tracker](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/4019). It is caused by Microsoft only testing C# with space-based indentation.

The so-called "Workaround" is miserable, but still, it is to change your settings from using tabs to spaces.

There are a plethora of other issues (Namely with the [C# Auto Formatter](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/4014) that cause tab-based work to be terrible in VS2015 until a patch comes out.

**Edit:**

There is now an extension available on VS Gallery, [GoToDefinition Fix](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7c807aa8-40a4-4c75-9c46-e0ba8b34a367), which will serve well as a temporary fix for this issue.

**Edit:**

Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 [CTP](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2015/10/08/visual-studio-2015-update-1-ctp.aspx) and [RC](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2015-update1-vs.aspx) variants both fix this issue, but the RC is the latest and should be installed instead of CTP if you are running it. Many formatting issues are addressed by these updates, and tabs are, basically, usable again.

Comment: OMG! How embarrassing for MS! Just checked, that the source code can contain tabs instead of spaces, just flip a relevant checkbox in the Tools\Options for a moment and the F12 works straight after that.

Comment: see https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/4019 for the issue on github. and https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7c807aa8-40a4-4c75-9c46-e0ba8b34a367 for a workaround using an extension

Comment: Microsoft clams that they fixed it with [VS 2015 CTP 1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2015/10/08/visual-studio-2015-update-1-ctp.aspx)

Comment: It is, in fact, fixed. However, there appear to be some oddities with intellisense and lambdas in said preview.

Comment: Lol this issue IS STILL LIVE at VS2017 Official Release wtf. (Even after a VS restart lol)

Comment: @AgentFire: Having a ball with this over at [DeveloperCommunity](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/181887/unable-to-see-definitions-in-newloaded-c-projects.html). :P